# Is there any way to fast read pixel value using gdal in C#

Tags: gdal, c#

I create with C# a series of lat/lon value pair in the code(using i, j loop) and I want to extract the pixel value based on either lat/lon pair or pixel location (i, j).

I know there is one gdal utility called [gdallocationinfo](http://www.gdal.org/gdallocationinfo.html) which can read pixel value very fast. But it is written in python.

I am wondering whether there is a way to use this gdal utility in my C# code, or other methods that can extract pixel value in a faster manner.

**Final solution:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Gdal.AllRegister(); //Register all gdal data drives
        List<int> resolutionId = new List<int>() { 9 };

        Dataset ds = Gdal.Open("D:/SKnoZero.tif", Access.GA_ReadOnly);   //Read raster
        double[] gt = new double[6];
        ds.GetGeoTransform(gt); //Read geo transform info into array
        int Rows = ds.RasterYSize;  //Get the number of rows 
        int Cols = ds.RasterXSize;  //Get the number of columns
        Band band = ds.GetRasterBand(1);    //Read band 1
        double startX = gt[0];  //Upper left lon
        double startY = gt[3];  //Upper left lat
        double interval = gt[1];    //Cell size
        double x, y;    //Current lon and lat

        var filePath = "D:/SKcsv.csv";
        using (StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(filePath))
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < Rows; k++)  //read one line at a time
            {
                y = startY - k * interval;  //current lat
                int[] buf = new int[Cols];
                //ReadRaster parameters are StartCol, StartRow, ColumnsToRead, RowsToRead, BufferToStoreInto, BufferColumns, BufferRows, 0, 0
                band.ReadRaster(0, k, Cols, 1, buf,Cols,1,0,0);
                //iterate each item in one line
                for (int r = 0; r < Cols; r++)  
                {
                    if (buf[r] != -32768)   //if pixel value is not NoData value
                    {
                        x = startX + r * interval;  //current lon                             
                        var geoidpair = GetVrgId(x, y, resolutionId);   //get geoid
                        var temp = geoidpair;
                        var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}{4}", x, y, buf[r], temp[0], Environment.NewLine);
                        csv.Write(newLine);           
                     }
                 }
         }
         Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
         Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
         Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Have you successfully implemented GDAL in C#?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Not yet. Other parts of my code have no relation with gdal.

Comment: gdallocationinfo is written in C not python. It uses RasterIO to read the pixel (line 475), this is available in C#.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Oh gosh! This saves my life! Thank you! I only use it in OSGEO shell. Thought it is written in python. Is there source code in C# version?

Comment: The C# is a p-invoke layer written using SWIG. It works great. I use it in a significant application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using OSGeo.GDAL for this code. It is extracted from my own working code but is incomplete, it will show you the basics of opening and reading a raster using GDAL.

The source for GDAL is downloadable, there is mostly C and C++ but some python... no C# that I know of - C# is windows only, GDAL is multi-platform. Many times I have referred to the source code for examples of what works and what doesn't. With C# you're mostly on your own as no really good documentation exists you can look at [this](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrCsharpRaster) though.

The ReadRaster parameters are StartRow, StartCol, ColumnsToRead, RowsToRead, BufferToStoreInto, BufferColumns, BufferRows, 0, 0. I hope that helps.

```
using OSGeo.GDAL; // way up the top

OSGeo.GDAL.Dataset pInDS;
pInDS = Gdal.Open(InImage.Text, Access.GA_ReadOnly);

// if the requested pixel is out of range return an error
// for that you need the range.
Rows = pInDS.RasterYSize;
Cols = pInDS.RasterXSize;

double[] pGT = new double[6];
pInDS.GetGeoTransform(pGT);
int col = (int) (X - pGT[0]) / pGT[1]
int row = (int) (pGT[3] - Y) / -pGT[5]

// pReadBlock is an array of the raster data type, you will need to duplicate that
// code dependent on each data type
OSGeo.GDAL.Band pInBand = pInDS.GetRasterBand(1);
bool IsThereAnError = pInBand.ReadRaster(row, col, 1, 1, pReadBlock, 1, 1, 0, 0);
Value = pReadBlock[0];
```

You might need to modify your reference path to include the GDAL bin/lib directory so it can find required libraries an I think you may need to link a specific lib *GDAL_i.lib*.

The geotransform array goes like this:

```
GeoTransform[0] = Xmin;             // Upper Left X
GeoTransform[1] = CellSize;         // W-E pixel size
GeoTransform[2] = 0;                // Rotation, 0 if 'North Up'
GeoTransform[3] = Ymax;             // Upper Left Y
GeoTransform[4] = 0;                // Rotation, 0 if 'North Up'
GeoTransform[5] = -CellSize;        // N-S pixel size
```

Note that the geotransform is from the upper left and cells are negative in the Y dimenstion. It is explained [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_datamodel.html).

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you Michael! I modified my code according to yours. I am wondering is there a way to check whether the raster is successfully read. When transferring the line starting with bool-----, there is an error saying that the type is not convertible between left and right sides. Because the value (-32768 as nodata value) I got from the code is not the true pixel value. I guess the raster is not successfully read?

Comment: My code:  int[] buf = new int[1]; Band band = ds.GetRasterBand(1);  band.ReadRaster(0, 0, ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize, buf, 1, 1, 0, 0);  int value = buf[0]; Console.WriteLine(value);  The value I got is wrong.

Comment: It's band.ReadRaster(row,col,1,1... you will need the geotransform to resolve X and Y to row and col, I will put that in.

Comment: @shirleydd: RTB. The C# API is nearly exactly the C++ API, so whatever you read on the gdal site applies. ReadRaster returns the same CPLErr as the C++. These are enums in C#.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson: C# is *NOT* Windows-only. This is a common misconception. Mono implements the CLR on Android, Linux, and OSX. The UI libraries are different, but the non-GUI stuff works fine. I myself have written C# on Win7 using VS Pro 2012, and run it *without recompiling* on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian.

Comment: Fair enough @Reilly, I sit corrected. I am aware of windows emulators on linux but have no experience with that OS, Mac OS or Android to base my opinions on. Generally I use C++ when using GDAL objects - unless I need a form, the C# forms are so much more convenient; you are right, the API is *almost* the same, just be aware that it's only *almost* the same or it will come back to bite!

Comment: @Reilly Thanks! Good to know that they are similar. I think C++ code samples are more than C# code samples.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Thank you! This piece of code really does me a big favor! Thank you also for explaining the parameters of readraster, which is really helpful for me to understand. I guess one small typo is in "ReadRaster(row, col, 1, 1, pReadBlock, 1, 1, 0, 0)", the first and second would be switched? So should be ReadRaster(col, row, 1, 1, pReadBlock, 1, 1, 0, 0)? I also would like to ask one more question: could I avoid reading NoData pixel with some good strategy(like putting some keyword)? Right now I can check the value after I get the pixel value.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson So basically my workflow is: create pixel lat/lon---->get pixel value based on lat/lon---->create uniqueid based on lat/lon--->check whether pixel value==NoData value--->if yes, write lon,lat,pixel value, and uniqueid to csv file. Above is the workflow. I loop this with i from 0 to maxColumn and j from 0 to maxRow. The raster I use contains like half numbers of pixels with NoData value. With my current workflow, I have to loop the entire raster and check the pixel value after I get it. I am wondering whether there are some insights to improve the workflow. Thank you!

Comment: Why not read the raster one line (row) at a time and iterate through the values returned, instead of 1,1 for a pixel make it the raster cell width. GDAL also has a ReadBlock which is faster; some rasters have a block that is a row, others like tiled TIFF have blocks that are 128x128 but if you're reading the whole raster that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Thanks a lot! I just modified my code to implement this method(read one line at a time) and it works fantastically! I want to somehow paste my code...don't know how...

Comment: That's great news. You can do more than one line but I don't find that to be much faster and you have to keep track to ensure you don't try to read outside the image. Now that it's working please accept the answer so future users can see that it helped.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Yup! I marked that. The running time is very promising using this method! I also edit the original post with final solution code. Hope it will help other people. If you have future comment about the code. I would like to hear. Thanks again!!